# Linq Query to parse/fetch content from this XML (WSDL)

Tags: .net, c, xml, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<types>
      <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/"
                 targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/"
                 elementFormDefault="qualified">
         <xs:include xmlns:wsdl11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                     xmlns:soap11enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                     schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/static/Included.xsd"/>
        <xs:include xmlns:wsdl11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                     xmlns:soap11enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                     schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/static/Included.xsd"/>
         <xs:element name="echoInclude">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="ex:include"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
   </types>
</definitions>
```

In the above XML I want to fetch the value of  **schemaLocation** attribute of every xs:include  element which is inside xs:schema element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, load the XML document, set Namespace and query the element name.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
 XNamespace ns= "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

 var nodeList = from ele in doc.Descendants(ns + "schema").Descendants(ns + "include")
                  select ele.Attribute("schemaLocation").Value;

 foreach (var t in nodeList)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(t);
  }
```

Comment: do u think it should be something like doc.Descendants.Descendents because xs:schema is inside types which is inside document , hence it is not working

Comment: Consider my post as reference. You may try - doc.Descendants(ns + "schema").Descendants(ns + "include")